# Finding values from array in hash key and return counts of zero

Tags: perl

I have one array which I am checking for values in a hash (which I created). The idea is to check each element of the array if exists in the hash keys. If it does not exists, it should say that the non-existent element appears zero times. The hash I created to count frequency of numbers on a second array.

Here's what I did:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {
    
    my @Source = ("A", "B", "D");
    my @ArrToHash = ("A", "C", "A", "B", "E", "F");
    
    my %hashy;
    ++$hashy{$_} for @ArrToHash;
    
    foreach my $e (@Source) {
        if (exists $hashy{$e}) {
            print "$e are $hashy{$e}\n";
        }
    }
}
main();
```

I am getting

> A are 2
>
> B are 1

While in reality I would like:

> A are 2
>
> B are 1
>
> D are 0

Any clue? How to fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (exists $hashy{$e}) {
        print "$e are $hashy{$e}\n";
    }else{
        print "$e are 0\n";
    }
```

**OR**

```
    printf "%s are %d\n", $e, $hashy{$e} // 0 ;
```

---

**Comment:**
I prefer `$hashy{$e} // 0`.  It returns `$hashy{$e}` if `$hashy{$e}` exits and it is not undef.
Ikegami prefers `$hashy{$e} || 0`. It returns `0` also when `$hashy{$e}` is an empty string. It works with older perl versions without `//` operator support.
IMHO  It is a matter of "style-guide" in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (exists $hashy{$e}) {
    print "$e are $hashy{$e}\n";
} else {
    print "$e are 0\n";
}
```

or just

```
printf "%s are %s\n", $e, $hashy{$e} || 0;
```

If you actually want zeros in the hash,

```
my %hashy;
$hashy{$_} = 0 for @Source;
++$hashy{$_} for @ArrToHash;
```

Comment: the else, should be _$e are 0_ actually!

Comment: Sorry, tired, that's what I meant. But hey, you got the point, and that's what counts :) Fixed.